# How do I Change C# Gridview data when I select a different item in an asp:DropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

When I select a new item in my `asp:DropDownList`, I want the data in my `asp:GridView` to reflect info based on the newly selected item in my `asp:DropDownList`.

my aspx.cs:

```
protected void ddlTaskList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //dsMail.UpdateParameters
    //lblCreateDistList.Visible = true;
    dsMail.UpdateParameters.Add("@TaskID", DbType.Int32, ddlTaskList.SelectedValue);
    grdEmails.DataSource= dsMail;
    grdEmails.DataBind();


}
```

my aspx:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="ddlTaskList" eventname="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaskList" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTaskList_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMail" runat="server" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EagleEyeConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="stpGetEmailDataByTaskID">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="1" FormField="ddlTaskList.DataValueField" Name="TaskID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdEmails" Runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            SkinID="Professional">
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="NameLnk" DataTextField="Name" DataNavigateUrlFields="Name" 
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="#?Name={0} " />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskDesc" HeaderText="TaskDesc" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TaskDesc" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

      </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Not sure what I'm missing, but I think I'll know when I see it!!

Thanks in advance,

Dan B.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void ddlTaskList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //dsMail.UpdateParameters
    //lblCreateDistList.Visible = true;
    dsMail.UpdateParameters.Add("@TaskID", DbType.Int32, ddlTaskList.SelectedValue);
    grdEmails.DataSource= dsMail;
    grdEmails.DataBind();

    UpdatePanel.Update();

}
```

try updating the panel when your dropdown fires
also add conditional mode to the update panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
```